# Wamp server URL was not found

Tags: php, iis, wamp

I have changed my apache port from 80 to 81 as on port 81 IIS was running.

Now if I start wamp server and write localhost:8081 I can visit phpmyadmin successfully

but I cannot run my php file when i write localhost:8081/test.php

test.php is in www folder of wamp64.

```
         Not Found
         The requested URL was not found on this server.

         Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12 Server at localhost Port 8081
```

Comment: If you changed the port from 80 to 81, why do you try to use port 8081?

Comment: 8080 is an alternative to 80 - they're not the same thing. Try either changing your port to 8081 or connecting on localhost:81   (pretty much just as Nico says)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the server with the port number which you have assigned. Since the default port for IIS & wamp server is 80, you need to change one of the ports.

another thing you can try is open the file(httpd-vhosts.conf),add"#add " Require all granted"then like this(remember to reboot the apache server):

Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www/snipe-it/public"
<Directory "F:/wamp/www/snipe-it/public">
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
#add " Require all granted"
Require all granted
#add " Require all granted"
```